# Change "Page not found" to "This question was migrated" for migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, 404-not-found

*Question updated after comment session with @anna-lear.*

If you hit [redirected question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file) there is addition at the bottom:

> migrated from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294185/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file?noredirect=1) Nov 28 '11 at 13:10
>
> This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

You can follow that link which leads you to this question's [old location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294185/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file?noredirect=1).

Which is actually a 404 page.

I suggest to change that, so instead of 404 page you would see something similar to this:

> This question was migrated to [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file), out site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems.

Comment: Migrated questions should automatically redirect to the destination site, not result in a 404. Do you have a couple examples of links that behave this way handy?

Comment: @AnnaLear I did not notice `noredirect=1` in the URL. My bad.

However, this 404 page could be saying that it is actually a redirect-page. I mean, it could contain a mention of `noredirect=1` in the text or be a complete different type of page similar to wikipedia redirects.

Comment: @AnnaLear should I update my question?

Comment: Sure, edit your request as you like. I'm personally not sure this is worth doing (it's not normal for noredirect links to exist "out in the wild" in my experience), but that doesn't mean the request to change this behaviour or how we handle it isn't worth making.

Comment: I agree with Anna. The only place you see that noredirect link is in the migration notice on the other site. So the user *already knows* it's migrated, so is there really any point in a custom page?

Comment: The link in the redirected question now leads to [revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8294185/revisions) instead of [404 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294185/how-to-write-properly-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file?noredirect=1).